# Fixing the double margins bug for inline-block elements Sass

Tags: html, css, sass, pseudo-class

I started learning sass this week and i made a layout for gallery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ic0o09988/neaZW/1/) is what i've done so far.

You will notice how i'm using

```
<!--
--><section class="item"></section><!--
--><section class="item"></section><!--
-->
```

for fixing the whitespaces between inline elements.
I also succed in fixing the double margins from left and right, but as u can see in the fiddle 
there are some double margins after the first row **On the top/bottom side** . Could somebody help me with fixing it ?

PS: i was thinking of somekind of a pseudo-selector to select every element after the first row .

Comment: Whitespace has nothing to do with margins.

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/132-quick-useful-case-sass-math-mixins/

Comment: When you mention double margins are you referring the 0.3% left margin on each item? The only double up I notice is due to browser subpixel rounding (e.g. some margins are rounded to 1px, some 2px). My personal preference when creating these sort of reponsive grids is to use fixed width padding to create gutters (e.g. the gutter is always exactly 1px). If it's useful I can create a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: sry i should edit the Question I'm having problem with the double margins from top/bottom side of the items (tested in Chrome )

Comment: Ah OK. It's easier to see when the top and bottom margin are set to zero. I have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.item` elements

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the white-space from top/bottom :)

Comment: Yeah, I forget to add that declaration every time I do an inline-block grid ;)